# Best Project and Client Management software

Tags: project-management

Does anyone know of a good and preferably free project management software (app) where I can basically manage invoices etc.

So I can add payment details for each project and Client and if it's overdue an email is sent to me. I can ever mark it as paid etc.

Does such an amazing web app (self hosted) exist or is it my next project? (Any collaborators for an open source project around?)

Thanks!

Comment: Try a google search for 'project management software'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software don't belong here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to make my own tool with Laravel. It is open source, if anyone wishes to use it. I made it so I can create clients, projects and invoices and clients can also pay through the site with Stripe integration.

https://github.com/shivampaw/UltimateCRM

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would keep things as simple as possible in the beginning. As a first pass, put together a simple spreadsheet. When you find you have outgrown that (could take a while), I would recommend something like Freshbooks (https://www.freshbooks.com/pricing). I have been using Freshbooks as my invoicing/accounting software for several years now and have been quite pleased. However, I am starting to outgrow that platform and will likely transition to Quick Books in the near future.

I often find newer freelancers / small business owners fretting about which tools to use and wasting time looking for "the perfect tool." Remember that the goal of your tools is to save you time, and often the best tools are the simplest. While there is a SaaS product for everything, I nearly always start with a spreadsheet, and only when I truly outgrow the spreadsheet do I start looking for a better tool.